# How to put imageview above xml layout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I'm using popup window with constraint layout and need to put the image above that layout.What is the best way to do it?

[image]

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Use this xml file...set round image in ImageView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/diam10"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/diam40dp">


        <TextView

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/diam15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_bottom_line"
            android:drawablePadding="@dimen/diam5dp"
            android:maxLength="15"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/diam5dp"
            android:text="Sample Example"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_round_shape_drawable"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:padding="@dimen/diam15dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this help you...if any issue let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this by applying your properties, set background image in circle image view :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="95dp"
            android:text="TEST TEXT"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:background="#808080">

        </TextView>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/circleImageViewProfile"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
                android:src="@drawable/solid_circle" />

        </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

For using `CircleImageView` you have to add a gradle:

```
 compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
```

By this code, you will get this type of layout. see this image:

[image]